# Python - Check If string Is In bigger String

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm working with Python v2.7, and I'm trying to find out if you can tell if a word is in a string.

If for example i have a string and the word i want to find:

```
str = "ask and asked, ask are different ask. ask"
word = "ask"
```

How should i code so that i know that the result i obtain doesn't include words that are part of other words. In the example above i want all the "ask" except the one "asked".

I have tried with the following code but it doesn't work:

```
def exact_Match(str1, word):
    match = re.findall(r"\\b" + word + "\\b",str1, re.I)
    if len(match) > 0:
        return True
    return False
```

Can someone please explain how can i do it?

Comment: use  single backslash in raw strings.

Comment: What Casimir is basically saying is either use `r"\b"` or use `"\\b"`. In your snippet, the correct call would thus be either `r"\b" + word + r"\b"` or `"\\b" + word + "\\b"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following function :

```
>>> test_str = "ask and asked, ask are different ask. ask"
>>> word = "ask"

>>> def finder(s,w):
...   return re.findall(r'\b{}\b'.format(w),s,re.U)
... 
>>> finder(text_str,word)
['ask', 'ask', 'ask', 'ask']
```

Note that you need `\b` for boundary regex!

Or you can use the following function to return the indices of words :
in splitted string :

```
>>> def finder(s,w):
...   return [i for i,j in enumerate(re.findall(r'\b\w+\b',s,re.U)) if j==w]
... 
>>> finder(test_str,word)
[0, 3, 6, 7]
```

Comment: @FranciscoF read complete doc in https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Comment: **DON'T** use `str` for variable names because this overrides the [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) function.

Comment: I have a problem, the word is in utf-8 and this gives me an error.

Comment: @FranciscoF What kind of error? you can also use `re.U` flag in `findall` function!